# Unable to disable a message on top of VI

Tags: vim, vi

I am not sure, any time I open VI I get a weird "No text" message in the top. Ig I now try typing on the top line, the "No Text" message gets superimposed on it. Is there any setting that will disable this. My VIMRC file has the following header related settings. I have tried disabling them without much help.
  set showtabline=1

This is driving me nuts. any help is much appreciated.

[image: Weird Vi Top Header]

Comment: Does `ctrl-L` or `:redraw` remove the text? If yes, add this command to your `.vimrc`: `autocmd VimEnter * redraw!`.

Comment: I tried that. Unfortunately that did not seem to have helped.

Comment: Finally I found what the issue is and it has nothing to do with vi. It is apparently a konsole bug as decribed here https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=196177